# How to get iTunes ID for a song in the iPhone music library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes, mpmediaquery

I'm querying the iPhone media library using MPMediaQuery and getting a list of all the artists and albums.
How do I get the iTunes ID for each artists, album or song so I can uniquely identify it?
Just searching by name can be not very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID in the MPMediaItem documentation, it identifies each media item uniquely.

Comment: But from what I understand it identify it just on the same device. I'm looking for a way to actually find the artist/song in iTunes (or other music services) in order to show additional info

Comment: I'd say you might be better off then looking at the database you want to query first and finding what they are looking for. A starting point might be... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_music_databases

Answer (score 0):

The library https://github.com/gangverk/iTunesSearch has a getIdForArtist method.